# Auto increment field on update

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark

I have a field called: update_count, which I need to reflect the number of times a row has been updated.

I have been looking into the SERIAL type for the column which sounds promising, but it has one problem - it is [not transaction safe](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-serial/), which means that it may get out of sync. This may not happen.

My question is then: "How to handle an auto incrementing field on each column while supporting multiple concurrent client?"

Environment: Spark.

Answer (score 1):

Auto-increment (aka "identity") columns are something completely different than "a column indicating the number of updates to a row".

Even if a sequence (the "magic" behind identity columns) did work without gaps, you still have a single sequence for the entire table, not for each row.

If you want to track how often a row was updated, create a trigger:

```
create or replace function increment_update_count()
  returns trigger
as
$$
begin
  new.update_count := new.update_count + 1;
  return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

And create the corresponding trigger:

```
create trigger trigger_track_upate_count
  BEFORE update on the_table --<< change your table name here
  for each row
  execute procedure increment_update_count();
```